# Sql How To Count And Arrange Order Of Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have One Table Sale
two Colums

```
_______________________
Store_name | Sale_Item |
_______________________ 
abc Store      |  Xyz Candy|
abc Store      |  Xyz Candy|
abc Store      |  Xyz Candy|
abc Store      |  Xyz Candy|
gfh Store      |  Xyz Candy|
abc Store      |  Xyz Candy|
gfh Store      |  Xyz Candy|
gfh Store      |  Xyz Candy|
gfh Store      |  Xyz Candy|
gfh Store      |  Xyz Candy|
gfh Store      |  Xyz Candy|
```

How i  count Stores Sale And Arrange order by Top sale
Eg 
Result

```
_______________________
Store_name | Sale_Item |
------------------------
gfh Store       |  6    |
abc Store       |  5    |
```

See gfh counted Sale And  value is 6  So Gfh Is Top
And Abc Is Lowest Sale And Counted Value is 5 So its Down 
Basically My Question Is How To Count And Arrange Order Of Data

Comment: You have a table? In mysql?

Comment: Why Do You Capitalize almost Every Word In Your Question?

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`. This is beginner SQL.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. You can start from here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 2):

```
Select store_name,count(store_name) as number_of_stores 
from sale 
group by store_name 
order by count(store_name) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

Use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT store_name,
COUNT(*) AS sale_item
FROM sale 
GROUP BY store_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba0c4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT store_name, COUNT(*) AS store_sale FROM sale GROUP BY store_name ORDER BY store_sale DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL request :

```
SELECT store_name, count(*) AS nbr_sale_item 
FROM sale GROUP BY store_name 
ORDER BY nbr_sale_item DESC
```

This request should display what you're expecting

Comment: Please Correct Your Answer You was Not add Order by desc ;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT store_name,COUNT(*) AS sale_item 
FROM sale 
GROUP BY store_name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT store_name, COUNT(*) AS sale_item FROM sale GROUP BY store_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```